# Linked List Find Function C++

Tags: c++

How would you go about implementing a find function in a non templated C++ linkedList?

The remove function is implemented in the following way:

```
 bool LinkedList::remove(Node* n)
 {
      Node *temp = front, *prev = 0;

      for(int i = 0;i < size; i++)
      {
           if (temp == n) 
           {
                if (temp == front)
                {
                     front = n->next;
                } 
                else 
                {
                     prev->next = temp->next;
                }

               delete temp;
               size --;
               return true;
          }
          prev = temp;
          temp = temp->next;
     }
     return false;
}
```

Comment: Go through the list, node by node, and check if the node you're at compares to the node you're looking for. `if (current == tofind) break;` or something

Comment: I wouldn't... I would use `std::list` (if I really had to use a list) and use `std::find`.

Comment: What has the remove function to do with a find function? What would be the parameters of the find function? a Node* like for the remove function? Or a Value to compare with the Nodes' values? Or even a predicate function?

Comment: Why this long remove...? at least ad the check for node to be in the list only on DEBUG... use std::list... it will be faster and...

Comment: Instead of 'delete temp' do 'return temp'. Figure out the rest... Oh, you'll have issues with 'front = ...'.

Comment: Also get used to use ++i in for loops.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hint: the `remove()` function already does almost everything that `find()` will need to do. You just need to figure out which bits to keep and which to get rid of. The stuff you'll need to add is going to be minimal, if any. It will depend on `find()`'s API, which you're not specifying.